# How to implement a hybrid microservice supporting both a PUB/SUB mechanism and an API?

Tags: python, rest, microservices, publish-subscribe

Suppose one needs a Python microservice that:

1. Subscribes to certain types of events (from the central event bus) and processes them as they come; emits different types of output events (to the same event bus) in response to processing incoming events.
2. Provides an additional API (e.g. REST + JSON) at the same time.

The question is whether this is feasible at all and what is the best way to implement such a microservice. I do understand how to support either 1 or 2 but have no idea how to support them both.

Any thoughts are appreciated.